# Empty value in decimal type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with a lot of rows and some cell value types are decimal. In some of the rows I need that the cell with decimal type is empty.
For example:
If the cell value is 0 then leave the cell empty not 0.
Is it possible to do? If yes, then how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `CellFormatting` event. You're going to get a value passed in from the event `args` that represents the unformatted value.

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties and set the null value to zero or use a loop for all cells and check their values